# Getting variable undefined when trying to call it in a function node.js

Tags: javascript, html, sql, node.js

I'm trying to get the text of an html element to be the same as a variable declared in js. But on the below code, `console.log` results in an undefined variable even though the variable is clearly defined. Why is it showing up as undefined?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var sqlResult = "sqlresult";

function fetchSql() {
        console.log(sqlResult);
        console.log("Inside fetchSql");
        document.getElementById('MixLabel').innerHTML = sqlResult;
}


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : "-------.--------east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user     : "------",
    password : "------",
    database: "innodb",
    port: "3306"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
    console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }

    connection.query("select * from users where username = 'maxolgin';", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
//        console.log(result);
        sqlResult = result[0].username;
        console.log(sqlResult);
    });

    console.log('Connected to database.');
});

app.get('/init', function (req, res) {
    init();
    // res.send(...), etc.
});
```

Comment: not reproducible, please add a [mcve]

Comment: I could see how that was not reproducible. Maybe this is reproducible now?

Comment: Please separate the server-side code from the client-side code, currently it appears mixed together.

Comment: No this is all server side code. Client is html I can include that too if that would help.

Comment: `document.getElementById('MixLabel').innerHTML = sqlResult;` is clearly clientside DOM manipulation

Comment: Hmmm. this is running in my app.js file which I thought was server side. Would posting the html code help you?

Comment: @supe is the code reproducible now?